# Swift TableView Pagination cells inside each other

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, tableview, paging

I want to make pagination. This code work. But after paging, while i am scrolling to top, i can see other cell inside old cell, they appear while creating. scrolling down ok but scrolling top, all cells show inside each other when i am scrolling to top fastly/normally
So what is wrong my code?

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        if indexPath.row % 3 == 0{
            cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PostCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! PostCell
        }else{
            cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PostCellWithImage", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! PostCellWithImage
        }
        if (indexPath.row == self.data.count-1)  && !firstTime{
            print("yüklenecek")
            self.loadingMorePostsActivityView.isHidden = false
            getData()
        }
        return cell
}

func getData(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2){
            var indexes = [IndexPath]()
            var startIndex = self.data.count
        for i in 0..<10{
            self.data.append(i)
            indexes.append(IndexPath(row: startIndex+i, section: 0))
        }
        self.loadingMorePostsActivityView.isHidden = true
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        print(self.data.count)
        self.firstLoad = false

        }
}
```